# Should I flag an answer if the answerer deletes comments asking for clarification?

Tags: support, comment, flagging

In an (old) question, I downvoted the accepted answer and gave my reason in a comment. As a consequence, a small dispute started which resulted in a bickering. The author of the accepted answer, having access to moderator tools, seems to have now deleted all comments to his answer – not only his own but mine and others’ as well (along with previous comments of the questioner himself asking for clarification on a different aspect).

I have now restated my original comment explaining my downvote. If the author deletes it again, should I flag the answer? Should I proceed differently?

Comment: Mod tool privileges or not, no user, except a mod, can delete others' comments.  Consider that they may have been flagged, and subsequently removed by a mod.  And by the may, "moderator tools" available to trusted users (who are not mods) aren't the same tools available to site moderators (diamond mods).

Comment: @amWhy Okay, follow-up question: why would a moderator delete a comment stating “I downvoted this because …” and along with it all *old* comments to the answer? That is, is there some policy I don’t know of? Is that accepted moderator behaviour?

Comment: I don't know the context, and can't see the comments. Many comments are deleted by mods, and it doesn't mean your comments were uncalled for.  But when a dispute ensues in the comment thread, sometimes they are deleted by a mod, when flagged, and the comment thread has extended into a long discussion/dispute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To confirm what amWhy already explained the comments were deleted by moderators, to be precise by now three of us (including me) were involved (though when you asked only two, still including me), and some of their own comments were also deleted by the original author of the answer.

The comment thread was a train wreck. The part in which you were involved became a hostile back-and-forth, in part about another question entirely, there was also some on-topic substance in between but presented in a form not really efficient to others. Plus, self-deletions made the thread confusing.

At first selective deletions were tried, I then decided to pull the plug entirely and delete everything. The old comments while harmless were not  all that useful either, especially after the original answerer had deleted theirs in part, and deleting everything is both easier and sometimes better as it sends a more clear message.

You repost was by now also deleted. It is fine that you explained your reasoning for the downvote at the start. But it is not that essential to have this information around, and the poster of the answer had expressed disapproval of the way you approached the situation.

To put it differently, what you said is not that informative either. "I downvoted this because I think that the first isomorphism is not trivial." 
 is not clear, and to the extent it is informative it is not all that useful.
Right, somebody found the answer too terse, which is a valid objection to be sure, and thus downvoted. This is fine, but it is not essential to have this recorded either.

To sum up, the comments got a deleted because they created  much more heat than light. If you think it is necessary to have more details there, please write your own answer to the post.

Comment: That’s fine, I get it. However, “*… the poster of the answer had asked you to express your objection in a different form, which you did not.*” – I have now reread the comment thread (from screenshots) and this is not true.

Comment: I rephrased. What I recounted was how the answerer saw it; but it is true that they did not literally ask what I said they asked (in any case not prior to your repost).